# PHPSpreadsheet cannot set worksheet margin

Tags: excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet

Hi I have a little problem with this plugin, this is the code that makes an error

```
Sheet::macro('setPageMargins', function (Sheet $sheet, float $top = 1, float $right = 0.75, float $bottom = 1, float $left = 0.75) {
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageMargins()->setTop($top);
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageMargins()->setRight($right);
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageMargins()->setLeft($left);
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageMargins()->setBottom($bottom);
});
```

Here is the error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet::setPageMargins() must be
>   an instance of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageMargins, float
>   given

and I just following this documentation https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#page-margins with using `maatwebsite\Excel`, by the way i'm using Laravel 5.7.

The question is how to set the margin? because I think the documentation is wrong, please help

Comment: Can you post a whole source that your are trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be doing:

```
// Create a page margins object.
$pageMargins = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageMargins();
$pageMargins->setTop(1);
$pageMargins->setRight(0.75);
$pageMargins->setBottom(1);
$pageMargins->setLeft(0.75);

Sheet::macro('setPageMargins', function($sheet, $pageMargins));
```

According to the code, it says `public function setPageMargins(PageMargins $pValue)`.

(https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/0e8fde9be6d3918ffe030bed0ba0297bfe330c4d/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php#L966)

Your `::macro` calls the `setPageMargins` function, although this pattern confuses me (it appears to be some `Maatwebsite\Excel` thing).

Comment: yes the macro function is from `Maatwebsite\Excel`, and I'll call something like this in the *Export*, `$event->sheet->mergeCells('S1:S4');`. Something like that will be called. and the macro function will be `Sheet::macro('mergeCells', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->mergeCells($cellRange);
        });`